# UICollectionView delegate's tap method not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, the datasource delegate works well, but `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didselect");
}
```

not get called, although i set the delegate (as i did with data source and it worked)
I have to mention that my cell is loaded from a nib and is connected to a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`, anyway the cells do not respond to my touch. I enabled the user interaction in the `UIImageView` that is in my cell.

also :

```
-(BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"this is caled");
    return YES;
}
```

is not getting called!

as I mentioned I did set:

```
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
```

and of course

```
<UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

also I don't have any `touchBegan` override ..

**UPDATE**:

WEIRD! it only gets called if I long press! how can I fix this, I set delaysContentTouches to NO plus i don`t have any gesture recognizers implemented.

help please. thanks.

Comment: How are you defining self.collectionView? Storyboard with outlet? Check that it is not nil when you are setting the delegate.

Comment: Any Luck fixing that? I just ran into the same situation today. Long Press also seem to be triggering the delegate.

Comment: Same problem here. Long press would select. And another collection view in the same project is working normally.

Comment: @henTdev Can you update the title of the question with appropriate words.

Comment: Same problem, is this an IOS 10 bug?

Answer (score 46):

It looks like there is a `UITapGestureRecognizer` somewhere up in the view hierarchy. By default, `UITapGestureRecognizer`s consume the touch that they recieve, meaning that it is not passed to the views below it in the hierarchy. You need to find the rogue tap gesture and add this line

```
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

This will make it pass touches to views below it in the hierarchy, and hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: This should be marked as the Correct answer! took me an hour to find this. thnx @aksh1t

Comment: Old but still best answer!! +1!!

Comment: Hi is it possible that this passes on through viewControllers? because I have cells that are very hard to tap, even though it's a decent size. The function just does not get called every time I tap.

Comment: View controllers themselves are not a part of the responder chain, their views are. Depending on the way your app is set up, there must be something (usually a tap gesture recognizer) that consumes the tap which you think is meant for the cells. You will need to find that view / tap gesture which is doing this and try to either remove it or not cancel touches.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you've added TapGestureRecognizer somewhere and it prevents selecton of cell. Check them, that should be the problem.

Comment: This is my problem. Could you expain why the GestureRecognizer would suppress the short tap but allowing the long one?

Comment: Work like a charm for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue, that clicking on the custom UICollectionView Cell, it was not detecting the click.
In my case, the problem was that in the CustomCell's Xib, the userInteraction was enabled and that's why UICollectionview's didSelectItemAtIndexPath was not getting called, instead user tap information was being sent to that particular cell for which I had no handler.

Comment: Thanks ! that worked for me for the same situation (cell loaded from a xib).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with PSUICollectionView (this works on iOS5 too) and I fixed it by putting a button on my CollectionViewCell and setting the target of that button
Also add tag's to know which button is pressed.

Comment: Thats what i did for now but its not the natural solution

Comment: I know, but sometimes you just want to move on.. And if it works, why not?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had TapRecognizer added in `self.view` due to which all taps in Screen is recieved at `self.view` not in `collectionViewDidSelect`.

So take care of this .

Answer (score 0):

in ur .h file, import CellViewController and add delegate

```
#import "myColleCell.h"

UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

in ur .m file,add the following codes to ur `ViewDidLoad`,

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"myColleCell" bundle:nil];
[myCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myColleCell"];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(220, 220)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[myCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

and setup cell with ur `CellViewController`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier= @"myColleCell";
    myColleCell *cell = (myColleCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setupCell:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //setup cell function methods placed in your CellViewController
    return cell;

}
```

and finally make sure that your cellView, collectionView are set user interactive to YES

Answer (score 0):

Ensure there aren't any objects setting the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` on the `UICollectionViewController`.

Similar to what other people are saying, I had this same problem and it was fixed by removing a call to `userInteractionEnabled` where the parent view was adding it as a child view controller. I was able to test this by adding a `UIButton` to the cell and determining that even it couldn't receive the touch events.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding here as a reference for other people who are looking for the answer**

**Short Answer:**

Delay the touches of default gesture recognizers associated with the tableview:

```
    if let gestures = tableView.gestureRecognizers{
        for gesture in gestures {
            gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        }
    }
```

**Explanation**

Every tableview has gesture recognizers associated with it. Which causes the delays of touches to custom UItableView cell. Set the *delaysTouchesBegan* to true so that the touch can be passed to subviews quickly.

In my case it was *CollectionViewController* inside *UItableViewCell* for which *collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath* was being called with a delay.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should use a tap gesture on the collection view.

Comment: nah it feels like a hack.

Comment: WEIRD! it only gets called if i long press! how can i fix this, i set delaysContentTouches to NO plus i don`t have any gesture recognizers implemented. tnx for your comments.

Comment: @henTdev That is weird! You should try it on a real device to see if it works properly there.

Comment: totally the same. that is the weirdest.

Comment: @henTdev I think it's best to use a tap gesture. I had the same problem and I use a tap gesture.

Comment: @henTdev are you sure you are not implementing didDeselect instead of didSelect?