# Delegate Methods of UICollectionView insider UITableView not called

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView`, with one of the cell containing an `UICollectionView`.

I have set the `UITableViewCell` as the delegate and datasource for the `UICollectionView`, and here I have implemented all the methods that I needed.

The problem is that it's like my `UICollectionView` doesn't respond to touchs events: nor the scrolling or the touch work.

So, the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:indexPath)` is never called.

The `UserInteractionIsEnabled` is set to TRUE to:

```
 1. TableView
 2. TableViewCell
 3. ContentView
 4. CollectionView
 5. CollectionViewCell
```

I don't really know what's wrong with my code.

this is the code for the TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class InsertSecondCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let COUNT = 12

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionView.reloadData()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return COUNT
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "categoryCell",
                                                      for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionCell

            cell.allergenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE")
            cell.titleLabel.text = "TITLE"
            cell.bottomViewm.isHidden = false
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5

            return cell


    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("hi")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: DataSource Methods work fine.

Comment: I have used the same method of having datasource and delegate in tableviewcell in another viewcontroller, and everything works fine.

Comment: your cell is called InsertDishSecondCell or secondSectionCell?

Comment: the first one is the name of the subclass of UITableViewCell, while the second one is the id that I gave to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

For the scrolling, do you have bounces and bounces vertically/horizontally checked in IB?

As for the selection, if you long press the cell, does it eventually print your message? You can add `tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false` to help the gesture recogniser transcend the view hierarchy more quickly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700437/uicollectionview-delegates-tap-method-not-getting-called).

Comment: I've bounces set, but it doesn't scroll at all.

And, although I long click, it doesn't print anything. 

I'm really having hard time to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Maybe try removing the delegate and datasource outlets you have connected in IB, and leave the `delegate/datasource = self` part you have in your UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. 
I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your code for the UITableView `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: I solved it by copying the cell from another viewcontroller in the storyboard. 

The code hasn't changed, I think it was an issue about constraints.