# collectionView :didSelectItemAtIndexPath called with a delay

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

I have a collection view which loads a list of products and there is no fancy functionality in it. It just loads data from API. The problem is that when i try to tap on one of the items in the collection view

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

is not getting called. But when i long press on a cell it gets called.

I am pretty sure that there are no gestures applied on the cell.

Can anyone give me some guidelines to tackle the problem.

The code base that i have is as follows

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cellTapped     =   (self.storeSearchListingCollectionViewOutlet.cellForItem(at: indexPath)) as! StoreSearchProdListingCollectionViewCell

        UStoreShareClass.storeSharedInstance.longTappedProductID = String(cellTapped.tag)

        if((UStoreShareClass.storeSharedInstance.longTappedProductID) != nil)
        {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchToProductDetailSegue", sender: self)
        }
        else
        {
            SetDefaultWrappers().showAlert(info:SERVER_DOWN_ERROR_ALERT, viewController: self)
        }
}
```

View Hierarchy is as follows

[image]

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: Whats your View Hierarchy ? is CollectionView Inside a ScrollView ? or other Subviews which have its own detection

Comment: Better to use view debugging and check is there any view on top of collectionviewCell's contententView.

Make sure you are reloading collectionView on mainThread

Comment: @iOSGeek Added view hierarchy screen in question

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman Didselect delegate function gets called when i press the cell for 3/4 seconds...

Comment: Have you applied "TapGesture" in your main view or on collectionview?

Comment: @Gati There are no gesture recognisers in the view or collection view

Comment: @JobinsJohn capture running screen on simulator or device in View Debugging and then check.

Comment: please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700437/uicollectionview-delegates-tap-method-not-getting-called

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. On the Storyboard go to the Collection View and uncheck **"Delay Touch Down"** in the Attribute inspector.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

May have two reasons:

1) May be first reason is:

Unfortunately your code is not getting main thread to work on UI. So you have to put your UI related part in MAIN thread like this.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
// PUT YOUR CODE HERE
            if((UStoreShareClass.storeSharedInstance.longTappedProductID) != nil)
            {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchToProductDetailSegue", sender: self)
            }
            else
            {
                SetDefaultWrappers().showAlert(info:SERVER_DOWN_ERROR_ALERT, viewController: self)
            }
    }
```

2) In second reason:

Have you made `collectionView` bouncing turned off? 
In Storyboard, make checked "Bounce on scroll" checkbox of `collectionView`, if unchecked.

[image: check this one!]

Answer (score 0):

For future readers of this old question - *probably me in the future* ;)

I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` which was swallowing my short taps (in the UICollectionView's grandparent) and hence only the old taps were making it through! I recon you have the same problem. You just need to add `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`!

```swift
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDidTouch(sender:)))
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all , put breakpoint in if condition and check if it gets inside the didselect block. Then,

Try adding your "performsegue" code in main thread like below

```
if((UStoreShareClass.storeSharedInstance.longTappedProductID) != nil)
{

 DispatchQueue.main.async 
{ 
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchToProductDetailSegue", sender: self)

}
}
else
{
    SetDefaultWrappers().showAlert(info:SERVER_DOWN_ERROR_ALERT, viewController: self)
}
```

Comment: It doesnt reach didSelct delegate method